# How does "dans l'absolu" compare to "en principe"?

Tags: choix-de-mot

For example, when I say this:

> Si tu comptes t'essayer à la randonnée dans le désert, méfie-toi des scorpions ! **En principe**, ils restent neutres, mais il se peut qu'ils se montrent très agressifs.
>
> {vs}: Si tu comptes t'essayer à la randonnée dans le désert, méfie-toi des scorpions ! **Dans l'absolu**, ils restent neutres, mais il se peut qu'ils se montrent très agressifs.

How does "dans l'absolu" compare to "en principe" in terms of nuance, usage, and register?

Comment: I wouldn't use *neutre* because that means not choosing a side in a conflict. Here is how I would rephrase your last sentence: *En général, ils restent indifférents à notre présence, mais il peut arriver qu'ils se montrent très agressifs.*

Answer (score 2):

I think both have kinda the same meaning, and both mean "In theory". Now I also agree with the other answers that in this case "Dans l'absolu" is not entirely appropriate, but I can't put my finger on the exact reason, maybe that's just a feeling.

Comment: "Formelle", tout est relatif... De plus les réponses en Anglais étant de la pure courtoisie, je doute qu'il y une règle imposant un quelconque niveau de language dans cette langue sur ce site précis. Finalement j'emploie ce même niveau de language sur d'autres sites stackexchange sans jamais avoir reçu cette remarque. Je n'ai donc aucun doute sur le fait qu'il ait sa place ici... pas de snobisme mal placé.

Comment: @Survenant9r7 > Certains écrivent "kinda", d'autres tutoient de prime abord, l'étiquette du language sur internet n'est pas la même. De plus "kinda" n'est pas similaire à "genre" en français, ca serait plutôt "like" qui aurait cet usage. Que ça fasse poseur, c'est votre point de vue, c'est en tout cas ma manière d'écrire ici, plutôt non-formelle, et je ne vais pas en changer à cause d'une remarque du premier snob venu. Finalement, je ne vois pas en quoi "kinda" pose un problème de "spelling, punctuation" ou "grammar", il s'agit uniquement d'une question de registre.

Answer (score 1):

**En principe** could be remplaced by "most of the time" (*"La plupart du temps"* / *"En général"*):

> Si tu comptes t'essayer à la randonnée dans le désert, méfie-toi des scorpions ! **La plupart du temps**, ils restent neutres, mais il se peut
>   qu'ils se montrent très agressifs.

**Dans l'absolu** could be remplaced by "in the majority of cases" (*dans la majorité des cas*):

> {vs}: Si tu comptes t'essayer à la randonnée dans le désert, méfie-toi des scorpions ! **Dans la majorité des cas**, ils restent neutres, mais il
>   se peut qu'ils se montrent très agressifs.

So in conclusion they both express the same idea but **Dans l'absolu** is stronger and less permissive than **En principe**.

Comment: I kinda disagree with this answer as for me "La plupart du temps" and "dans la majorité des cas" have the exact same meaning.

Comment: It's subtle but they do not represent the same degrees

Answer (score 1):

In your sentence 'En principe' fits as it is understood as 'En général'.

For me in your sentence 'Dans l'absolu' does not fit.
Use it when you start your sentences like that: 'Dans l'absolu je dirais que', 'Dans l'absolu on peut essayer de faire...'. It is something we employ a lot orally 
but more as a language fill-in word. Most of the time we should choose a better/different expression.

Btw: neutre is not appropriate here, 'inoffensifs' is better.

Answer (score 1):

First, what I'm going to say here is only about the "incise" version of "dans l'absolu", since there are many cases of use of that phrase that have a different grammatical value and therefore not comparable to "en principe" (e.g. "on raisonne dans l'absolu").

In many, if not most cases, the meaning and register are similar and the two expressions are interchangeable. That is the case in your example.

To try to find cases where the two cannot be interchanged, I did a web search for the expressions and found some (paraphrased) examples below.

Another example from the web where the two expressions are equivalent is:

> Dans l'absolu, nous privilégierons les projets immobiliers où le propriétaire est aussi le gestionnaire.

This means "in the general case," if the particulars of a case don't strongly indicate otherwise. It's used to introduce a generalization that may encounter exceptions.

But here are some cases where *dans l'absolu* is used and *en principe* wouldn't work:

> Dans l'absolu, un trou noir n'est ni un trou, ni noir.
>
> En cartographie, dans l'absolu, il n'y a pas de carte parfaite. Il n'y a que des cartes adaptées à un usage particulier.

In these cases, what is meant is that *when you look at it closely* or *when you think about it rigorously*, and contrasting with what may be a commonly held thought or a simple thought (that black holes are black or are holes, or that there is such a thing as the perfect map).

Using "en principe" here would have a different meaning because it would indicate strongly the possibility of an exception, for example:

> En principe, un trou noir n'est ni un trou, ni noir.

This would mean that in general, black holes are not black or holes, but with a hint that there may be cases where they are one of those things.

Answer (score -1):

Je n'utiliserais pas la version qui fait usage du complément circonstanciel « dans l'absolu » ; tout d'abord, je ne l'utiliserais pas parce qu'il est habituel de qualifier ce type de situation par « en principe » ; en essayant de comprendre si ce qui est exprimé correspond ou non à une réalité actuelle on se réfère à la définition suivante de l'adjectif « absolu » ;

> (TLFi) Dont l'existence ou la réalisation ou la valeur est indépendante de toute condition de temps, d'espace, de connaissance, etc.

La définition du Larousse en ligne est quasiment la même ;

> Loc. adv. Dans l'absolu, indépendamment de toute circonstance ou de toute condition. Raisonner dans l'absolu. Juger quelque chose dans l'absolu.

La nature inoffensive du comportement du scorpion est présentée donc comme une caractéristique de son comportement indépendante de tout environnement (on ne le trouve nulle part), de toute période (il n'en est pas question dans le temps) ; tout cela est déjà beaucoup trop prohibitif ;

on trouve cette idée d'une absence de référence au temps en rapport avec cette locution dans un exemple du TLFi ;

- Casse-cou! La mort vient.
  Elle vient pour tous les peuples : c'est une affaire de siècles.
  Vas-tu faire fi des siècles? La vie tout entière est une affaire de jours. Il faut être de sacrés diables d'abstracteurs, pour se placer dans l'absolu, au lieu d'étreindre l'instant qui passe.
  Que veux-tu? La flamme brûle la torche. On ne peut pas être et avoir été, mon pauvre Christophe.

Une nouvelle idée apparemment indissociable se trouve dans l'exemple suivant du TLFi ;
celle de l'inaccessibilité de l'absolu pour l'être matériel, sauf d'une certaine manière, à travers l'abstraction de la science, donc jamais en termes pratiques ;

- Un homme de génie est un homme absurde, c'est-à-dire qu'il pousse un système à l'absolu, or l'absolu est l'idéal de la science. On est fondé à croire que cet absolu existerait si nous connaissions tout (cause unique, c'est Dieu) mais comme nous sommes loin de tout connaître, nous ne pouvons pas agir en conséquence. En un mot, nous devons raisonner dans l'hypothèse de l'absolu, mais agir dans la réalité qui est autre, mais en faisant toujours comme si l'absolu existait ou devait exister; sans cela, pas de science.

Dans les exemples considérés le sens est celui de l'adjectif substantivé ;

> Empl. subst. L'absolu. Considéré comme un idéal de perfection ou comme hors d'atteinte pour l'homme

On retrouve ce contexte d'inaccessibilité à la perception humaine ; en fin de compte on conçoit que la considération de quelque chose de matériel dans l'absolu, n'a pas de sens.

La locution d'usage, « en principe », est la seule qui convienne, mis à part ses équivalents : « théoriquement », « logiquement » ; on peut ajouter « normalement », « sauf conditions particulières » et quelques autres de ce type, que l'on peut même inventer pour satisfaire à un contexte inhabituel.

> (TLFi) P. ext., usuel. En principe. [En incise, exprimant une réserve sur un événement devant logiquement se produire mais pratiquement restant aléatoire] Synon. logiquement, théoriquement.

Comment: Exceptionnellement digressif

Comment: @qoba Pas exceptionnellement explicatif

Comment: Si je peux me permettre, je ne trouve que cette réponse digresse tant que ça. Néanmoins j'avoue que sa longueur rend difficile l'exercice d'en sortir l'essence, même en étant locuteur natif. Mais on peut difficilement reprocher à quelqu'un d'être trop complet...

Comment: @LaurentS long ≠ complet. Les exemples donnés, bien que longs, ne contiennent pas la version en incise de l'expression "dans l'absolu", qui est pourtant la question. Des tartines sur le sens de "absolu" qui ne répondent pas à la question. Aucun exemple contenant "en principe". Une réponse expliquant la différence montrerait plus clairement les situations où utiliser l'une des expressions plutôt que l'autre aurait un sens différent. Je serais content de lire une réponse éclairante prouvant le contraire mais jusque-là penserai qu'il y a peu de différence de sens, à l'usage, entre les deux.

Comment: @qoba L'absolu est ce « Dont  la réalisation ou la valeur est indépendante de toute condition de temps, d'espace, de connaissance » ou  « qui est un idéal de perfection,  inaccessible » ; il est clair que **dans** cet état de chose c'est « dans l'absolu ». La différence est assez claire : considérer sur le plan de l'absolu ou encore « dans l'absolu » c'est considérer selon un degré extrême qui est inaccessible et non pas selon ce qui est plutôt un principe, ou une règle,  et très certainement pas absolue dans ce cas comme par exemple « Un scorpion qui ne pique pas est un scorpion mort. ».